# Vim line numbers get garbled in tmux

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmux, wsl-2

Running tmux on WSL Ubuntu 20, vim line numbers occasionally get fouled up. For example, in the below screenshot, line numbering is somehow disabled at line 4, and the corresponding text is left-shifted:

[image: Vim line numbers get garbled in tmux]

Comment: Use Vim's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl - I will log an issue, if I come up with a step-by-step way to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to issue a [redraw](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#CTRL-L) command (e.g., <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd>).